# spring security User details

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

My application has been developed using jsf2 , primefaces and spring 
I want to add user details bar on the above of page

This bar will contain String hello User, 
This bar appears only when user logged in

My problem is when access the application again , I see the bar while Logging process isn't performed

Any suggestions ?

The code of set bar visible is :

```
public String login() {
        boolean success = authenticationService.login(mail, password);

        if (success) {
            signedIn = true;
            User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String name = user.getUsername(); // get logged in username

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> login "+name);

            setName(name);
            return "facultyRating"; // return to
                                    // application
                                    // but being
                                    // logged now
        } else {
            signedIn = false;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("Login or password incorrect."));
            return "/pages/securityLogin.xhtml/loginPage.xhtml";
        }
```

this method exists in bean where Jsf2 page "that Contains user info bar" read from it
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code where you place the user bar?

Comment: I edited the post Kindly see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by making the info bar in separate secured page "Will appear only after Logging in "

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the login method is part of a session scoped managed bean, you could use the **signedIn** property to determine whether or not to show the menu bar using the rendered attribute of the component.

Something like the following:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <p:menubar rendered="#{authMBean.signedIn}">...</p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

The login method should also update the form where the user bar is placed in order to show it on login success.

```
org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":menuForm");
```

Comment: my problem is , this property is still true when other user access the application however I did that at @postconstruct method 
signedIn=false ;

Why this method doesn't called when another user access the application concurrency with current user

Comment: It's probably a scope problem. Chances are that you are not getting a new instance of that class when another user logis in. It's probably a good idea to post the rest of the code from that bean.